# bigO time complexity of algorithm to find Longest Substring Without Repeating

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
   //using a Collection to check if duplicate elements exist.
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList();
    for(int i =0; i< s.length();i++){
        String temp = Character.toString(s.charAt(i));
        if(str.contains(temp)){
            int idx = str.indexOf(temp);
            for(int j = 0; j<= idx;j++)  // clear all the elements before the duplicate elements, inluding the
                str.remove(0);          //duplicate. So, no elements collision in the new list.
            str.add(temp);
            count = str.size();  // update the count - the size of the new list.
        }else {
            str.add(temp);
            count++;
            if(count>max)
                max=count;
        }


    }        
    return max;

}
```

Hi, what are time and space analysis? I think space complexity is O(n), but time complexity depends on the numbers of duplicate characters because we remove element only if we meet the repeated character.
Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated, but related to your other question that was just deleted: please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Answer (score 0):

The space complexity is O(n^2) as you said.

But the time complexity will be O(n^2) because you are doing a linear search on arraylist every time to find if the char is repeated or not 
`if(str.contains(temp))` at this line. which is O(k) where k is the size of the arrayList

Consider an example of all unique elements

for i = 1 you will take 1 operation

for i = 2 you will take 2 operations

for i =n you will take n operations

total time complexity = O(1 + 2 + ... +n) = O(n^2)

Comment: But when we say BigO time, are we referring average case or worst case?

Comment: Your "all unique" case only happens in worst case, right?